# Create new KO.observable array and populate it from an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Is possible to create an `ko.observable` array and populate it using an array object?

My goal here is to create a `ko.observable` array with all the description/objects that are with the original array.

```
//Sample data the original data is coming from an socket query and being push on the array("people")
var people = [{
    name: "Contact 1",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "family"
  },
  {
    name: "Contact 2",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "friend"
  }
];.

var people = [{
    name: "Contact 1",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "family"
  },
  {
    name: "Contact 2",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "friend"
  }
];

var quotesarray = function(items) {
  this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
  this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  this.addItem = function() {
    if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
      this.items.push(this.itemToAdd());
      this.itemToAdd("");
    }
  }.bind(this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new quotesarray(people));

console.log(people);
```

Comment: pretty much u can do that, what's the issue you're into ?

Comment: @supercool the result is not defiend

Comment: do you mind keeping the code in fiddle and show the error i can help you to patch it up.

Comment: @supercool https://jsfiddle.net/zo8ygfk4/4/ here i just make a simple one

Comment: you should loop through item's (https://jsfiddle.net/zo8ygfk4/7/) . ko.applyBindings takes 1st param as viewModel. as you didn't mention any param in second, it takes document by default.

Comment: @supercool this works on a static array but its not working on my code since its coming from a socket i always encounter this erro 

Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Comment: well u should not call apply bindings multiple times until there is obsolete necessity . you can try this way https://jsfiddle.net/zo8ygfk4/17/ . hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to make it `items` instead of `quotesarray`

```js
var people = [
    { name: "Contact 1", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
    { name: "Contact 2", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "friend" }
];


var quotesarray = function(items){
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function(){
        if (this.itemToAdd() != ""){
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd());
            this.itemToAdd("");
        }
    }.bind(this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new quotesarray(people));

console.log(people);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>name</th><th>address</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works on a static array but its not working on my code since its coming from a socket i always encounter this error 

Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `observableArray` to which the socket writes messages. You `subscribe` to the array to be automatically notified when the contents change (i.e. after every write by the socket).

In the `subscribe` callback you empty the array and add the items to your viewmodel's property.

If you expect to receive many rapidly succeeding messages, you can `rateLimit` the array to which you write to ensure you don't update the DOM too many times.

Here's an example. The explanations are in the code comments.

```js
const UPDATE_EVERY_MS = 500;

// The observable array the socket writes to
const received = ko.observableArray([])
  // Use a rateLimit extension if you expect to
  // receive many updates from your socket
  .extend({ rateLimit: UPDATE_EVERY_MS });
  
// The observable array in your viewmodel
const rendered = ko.observableArray([]);

received.subscribe(items => {
  // Write "inbox" to viewmodel's list
  rendered(rendered().concat(items));
  
  // Clear received without triggering notification
  items.length = 0;
});

ko.applyBindings({ items: rendered });


// Mock a socket that writes to `received`
setInterval(() => received.push(Math.random()), 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: rendered">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```